# store and query json in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, data-modeling

I am trying to avoid anti-pattern in project where I must allow users to create, modify and delete table fields. So I am looking for storing JSON data in table. For example I have table products:

```
Products
----------------
id,
user_id,
created,
modified,
price,
_custom <-- there will be stored additional columns for each product needs
        {"adjustment":0.13, "weight":14.60, "have_some_individual_label":"value"}
```

But I can't see how it is possible to include `_column` parameters in query. For example, how to query all products where `user_id = 1` AND `have_some_individual_label = value`. Second parameter can be one, ore more (it will be used for filters and analytic). If this is bad approach - what would be better one? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If this is bad approach - what would be better one?

The [Entity–attribute–value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) model:

```
CREATE TABLE `ProductInfo` (
  `ProductID` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `AttributeKey` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `AttributeVal` VARCHAR(20),
  PRIMARY KEY (`ProductID`, `AttributeKey`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`ProductID`) REFERENCES `Products` (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO ProductInfo
  (`ProductID`, `AttributeKey`              , `AttributeVal`)
VALUES
  (         1 , 'adjustment'                ,         '0.13'),
  (         1 , 'weight'                    ,        '14.60'),
  (         1 , 'have_some_individual_label',        'value')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON approach you propose might be usable in case that you only want to compare for equivalence. I'd rather propose to store the extra individual attributes in separate table and link it to the Products table by it's ID.

```
CREATE TABLE custom_attrs(prodID int, customAttr varchar(32),
       customValue varchar(32));
```

This might be a better aproach, even though it brings some complexity to the table.